# Failure in adding href in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, struts, href

I'm trying to add a link in one .jsp page using the a tag but it's not working.
I have three jsp's in the Web Pages folder: index.jsp, login.jsp and page.jsp.

In my login.jsp i am doing:
 **[link](/index.jsp)** 
But it's not working.
What error am i doing?

```
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <html:form action="/login">
        <table border="0">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter your name:</td>
                    <td><html:text property="name" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Enter your email:</td>
                    <td><html:text property="email" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><html:submit value="Login" /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </html:form>
    <a href="/Web Pages/index.jsp"> hh</a>
</body>
```

Comment: please show us your jsp page

Comment: remove space from folder name.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like...
1. Move to a folder that does not have space...
2. Files that are inside /WEB-INF folder are not publicly accessible and we have to use servlet FController etc.